# URL lib encoding for array Python Requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, urllib

Hello hope you all are doing fine I am trying to do some URL encoding. as i am working with a third party api.

Case 1: Their documentation says location should be passed

```
[
    {
        'value': '42.0836,-78.4299',
        'distance': '100',
        'distanceUnit': 'miles'
    }]
```

When I pass that API return error but the same thing when i go to this website https://www.url-encode-decode.com/  and try encoding it online

```
%5B%0D%0A++++%7B%0D%0A++++%27value%27%3A+%2742.0836%2C-78.4299%27%2C%0D%0A++++%27distance%27%3A+%27100%27%2C%0D%0A++++%27distanceUnit%27%3A+%27miles%27%0D%0A++++%7D%0D%0A%5D
```

when I pass this on the API side seems like it works fine

Now in python, we can only encode Dict and not array

```
import urllib
import urllib.parse
import urllib

d = [
    {
        'value': '42.0836,-78.4299',
        'distance': '100',
        'distanceUnit': 'miles'
    }]


print(  urllib.parse.urlencode(d[0]))
```

API return error saying that Must provide valid locations array. Cannot deserialize the current JSON object

How do I encode an array in python with URL lib or anything else something like https://www.url-encode-decode.com/ website uses

any help would be a great help

finally, at the end, I pass all the param to the python requests module to make a post API

```
r = requests.get(url=XXXXX,headers = self.dic_headers,params=XXX,data={})
```

params are {} of key-value pair my location is one of key and value has to be URL encoded

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
import urllib
import json

d = [
    {
        'value': '42.0836,-78.4299',
        'distance': '100',
        'distanceUnit': 'miles'
    }]

encoded_url = urllib.parse.quote_plus(json.dumps(d))
print(encoded_url)
```

Output:

```
%5B%7B%22value%22%3A+%2242.0836%2C-78.4299%22%2C+%22distance%22%3A+%22100%22%2C+%22distanceUnit%22%3A+%22miles%22%7D%5D
```

You're making a get request here, instead of a post request:

> finally, at the end, I pass all the param to the python requests module to make a post API
>
> `r = requests.get(url=XXXXX,headers = self.dic_headers,params=XXX,data={})`

Comment: sorry i mean get request